# Calculation for Row Product Data

Tags: javascript, laravel, calculation

I want to add a function to 'calculaterowproductdata'. The 'sub_total' should be calculated by adding 'lens' and 'cutting_charge' multiplied by 'quantity', and then updating 'lens', 'cutting_charge' value to the field.

```
   function calculateRowProductData(quantity) {
       if(product_type[pos] == 'standard')
           unitConversion();
       else
           row_product_price = product_price[rowindex];

       $('table.order-list tbody tr:nth-child(' + (rowindex + 1) + ')').find('.discount').text((product_discount[rowindex] * quantity).toFixed({{$general_setting->decimal}}));
       $('table.order-list tbody tr:nth-child(' + (rowindex + 1) + ')').find('.discount-value').val((product_discount[rowindex] * quantity).toFixed({{$general_setting->decimal}}));
       $('table.order-list tbody tr:nth-child(' + (rowindex + 1) + ')').find('.tax-rate').val(tax_rate[rowindex].toFixed({{$general_setting->decimal}}));


       if (tax_method[rowindex] == 1) {
           var net_unit_price = row_product_price - product_discount[rowindex];
           var tax = net_unit_price * quantity * (tax_rate[rowindex] / 100);
           var sub_total = (net_unit_price * quantity) + tax;

           $('table.order-list tbody tr:nth-child(' + (rowindex + 1) + ')').find('.net_unit_price').text(net_unit_price.toFixed({{$general_setting->decimal}}));
           $('table.order-list tbody tr:nth-child(' + (rowindex + 1) + ')').find('.net_unit_price').val(net_unit_price.toFixed({{$general_setting->decimal}}));
           $('table.order-list tbody tr:nth-child(' + (rowindex + 1) + ')').find('.tax').text(tax.toFixed({{$general_setting->decimal}}));
           $('table.order-list tbody tr:nth-child(' + (rowindex + 1) + ')').find('.tax-value').val(tax.toFixed({{$general_setting->decimal}}));
           $('table.order-list tbody tr:nth-child(' + (rowindex + 1) + ')').find('.sub-total').text(sub_total.toFixed({{$general_setting->decimal}}));
           $('table.order-list tbody tr:nth-child(' + (rowindex + 1) + ')').find('.subtotal-value').val(sub_total.toFixed({{$general_setting->decimal}}));
       } else {
           var sub_total_unit = row_product_price - product_discount[rowindex];
           var net_unit_price = (100 / (100 + tax_rate[rowindex])) * sub_total_unit;
           var tax = (sub_total_unit - net_unit_price) * quantity;
           var sub_total = sub_total_unit * quantity;

           $('table.order-list tbody tr:nth-child(' + (rowindex + 1) + ')').find('.net_unit_price').text(net_unit_price.toFixed({{$general_setting->decimal}}));
           $('table.order-list tbody tr:nth-child(' + (rowindex + 1) + ')').find('.net_unit_price').val(net_unit_price.toFixed({{$general_setting->decimal}}));
           $('table.order-list tbody tr:nth-child(' + (rowindex + 1) + ')').find('.tax').text(tax.toFixed({{$general_setting->decimal}}));
           $('table.order-list tbody tr:nth-child(' + (rowindex + 1) + ')').find('.tax-value').val(tax.toFixed({{$general_setting->decimal}}));
           $('table.order-list tbody tr:nth-child(' + (rowindex + 1) + ')').find('.sub-total').text(sub_total.toFixed({{$general_setting->decimal}}));
           $('table.order-list tbody tr:nth-child(' + (rowindex + 1) + ')').find('.subtotal-value').val(sub_total.toFixed({{$general_setting->decimal}}));
       }

       calculateTotal();
   }
```

Comment: Where to data of get these ```lens``` and ```cutting_charge``` in the code?

Comment: @KeyboardCorporation  from input fileds
`<td><input type="number" class="form-control form-control-sm  lens" name="lens[]" value="{{$product_sale->lens}}" step="any" required/></td>
                                                        <td><input type="number" class="form-control form-control-sm  cutting-charge" name="cutting_charge[]" value="{{$product_sale->cutting_charge}}" step="any" required/></td>`

Answer (score 0):

Fetch the values of *lens* and *cutting_charge* first, then calculate it by passing to *sub_total* variable. And lastly, update the *sub_total* field:

```
function calculateRowProductData(quantity) {
    // ...

    var lens = parseFloat($('table.order-list tbody tr:nth-child(' + (rowindex + 1) + ')').find('.lens').val());
    var cutting_charge = parseFloat($('table.order-list tbody tr:nth-child(' + (rowindex + 1) + ')').find('.cutting-charge').val());

    var sub_total = lens + (cutting_charge * quantity);

    $('table.order-list tbody tr:nth-child(' + (rowindex + 1) + ')').find('.sub-total').text(sub_total.toFixed({{$general_setting->decimal}}));
    $('table.order-list tbody tr:nth-child(' + (rowindex + 1) + ')').find('.subtotal-value').val(sub_total.toFixed({{$general_setting->decimal}}));

    // ...
}
```

Comment: The **subtotal** is not updating.

Comment: Can you also provide the code of this ```calculateTotal()``` function?

Comment: "I will provide it

Comment: [https://github.com/EitsCloudPos/Calculation/blob/2caf12cc2b7af2f86ff233bb68b90d119b846a07/edit.blade.php]

Comment: Can you point where the part of value is not updating? Please check the value if its returning the correct data ```total += parseFloat($(this).text()); console.log(total);```. Do it also on other part of calculation that maybe not work or not passing the correct data.

Comment: Please check out this link. I have updated my complete code on GitHub. [https://github.com/EitsCloudPos/Calculation/blob/2caf12cc2b7af2f86ff233bb68b90d119b846a07/edit.blade.php]]